# When add comments in a function with Doxygen, can the function name output in the document be customized?

Tags: c, doxygen

```
/**
 * Set margain
 * @param 
 * @return
 */
JSFUNC_DECL(set_obj_margin_all) {}
```

Due to the use of macro, in the above code, the real function name is "setMarginAll", how can I output `setMarginAll` as function name in the document instead of `JSFUNC_DECL`.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? How is `JSFUNC_DECL` defined? why is in the code `set_obj_margin_all` and in the description `setMarginAll`, what is their relation?

Comment: macro JSFUNC_DECL is defined as: ```#define JSFUNC_DECL(func_name) JSValue func_name(JSContext* ctx, JSValueConst this_val, int argc, JSValueConst* argv)```. Another macro is introduced to set the need to display function name is ```setMarginAll``` in the documentation, ```setMarginAll``` is implemented by borrowing ```set_obj_margin_all```.

Comment: The version of Doxygen is 1.8.13

Comment: I try  ```Preprocessing``` configuration in Doxyfile, it resolves my problem.  ```Preprocessing```refs to https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html.